# Wifi connected- but does not access internet

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using Lenovo laptop e570, using Ubuntu 16.04.3.

While PC is connected successfully to wifi it fails reaching any website using Firefox, saying that i'm not connecting to server.
Conneting with a Windows PC to the same wifi succeeded.
what can be the reason for that prob? and how can i solve this?

Comment: Please supply `ping www.google.com` in your question

Comment: As well as: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.